# RealTimeDataBase shows different text depending on language device Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to use RealTimeDataBase from google to set content depending on the device's language?

Right now I have a different string.xml for this, but I would like to show this content with help from database from google.

For example, in a description of main screen shows content in English for english users, in russian for russians and so on, but taking this info from RealTimeDataBase, anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may store your content under the language node in the database. For example:

```
 - English:
 - - content1
 - - content2
 - French:
 - - content1
 - - content2
```

So you can get the device language and query the database with that parameter for the child. But you should handle the case where you don't have the content in the device's language.